# while using fgets and printf in C, it appears "00“ in the screen, do you know why and where "00" comes from?

Tags: c

I want print every line of one file, and I also want divide each line into several parts in a array and then use `atoi()` to change the string into `int`, but eventually I get a wired `00` in the end, I don't know where it comes from, can anybody help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tabu.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    int city[30][30];
    FILE *fp = fopen("/Users/wuchangli/Desktop/Cpractice/tabu_6010/tabu_6010_/tabu_6010_/30.in", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("error");
    }
    char data[20];
    int n = 0;
    char *token;
    int ct[3];
    int mm = 0;
    while (fgets(data, 30, fp) != NULL) {
        //fflush(stdin);
        //fflush(stdout);
        //fflush(stdin);
        //fflush(stdout);
        //printf("\n%s\n", data);
        printf("\n%s\n", data);
        token = strtok(data, " ");
        while (token != NULL && n > 0) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            ct[mm] = atoi(token);
            printf("%d\n", ct[mm]);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            mm++;
        }
        city[ct[0]][ct[1]] = ct[2];
        printf("%d", city[ct[0]][ct[1]]);
        city[ct[1]][ct[0]] = ct[2];
        printf("%d", city[ct[1]][ct[0]]);
        n++;
    }
    //for (int ii = 0; ii < 30; ii++) {
    //    for (int jj = 0; jj < 30; jj++) {
    //        printf("%d%d is %d\n", ii, jj, city[ii][jj]);
    //    }
    //}
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

here is the link of my files:[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_QwD2rnGfAVNjZNb2R0ZWs5SGM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues :-

in this part you are continuously increasing the mm++ but not initialize the mm again when you are going to read another line from file. issue is array bound error.

```
while(fgets(data, 30, fp)!=NULL){
        printf("data is = %s\n", data);
edited: mm=0;
        token=strtok(data, " ");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
                printf("token is = %s\n", token);
                ct[mm]=atoi(token);
                printf("%d....%d\n",mm,ct[mm]);
                token=strtok(NULL, " ");
                mm++;
        }
```

Second issue is :-

you have one arrey city[30][30], where row and column, both are 30.
in you code you reading a file that conation string like "30 435", and performed strtok() operation on each string and saved conversion of string to int in ct[0] = 30 and ct[1] = 435. you got issue because array bound checking.
ct[1] is 435 but you define city[30[30].

```
        city[ct[0]][ct[1]]=ct[2];
        printf("%d", city[ct[0]][ct[1]]);
        city[ct[1]][ct[0]]=ct[2];
        printf("%d", city[ct[1]][ct[0]]);
```